# How can I add vacation dates in Zoho projects?

Tags: zoho

I have an issue with the Zoho in my Zoho projects. I wanna add vacation dates in the Zoho, after that my work shift quickly and immediately after this change.

I wanna My recent works move quickly after modifying vacation dates in the Zoho.

Comment: Please read this [guide](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/) and update your question. Tip: use good grammar and punctuation. `I wanna` is not a good start.